# Change Background-color to button in APEX Oracle

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex

I want to change `background-color` to some buttons depending on a parameter

I was trying with a dynamic action to execute that javascript code.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){      
    var num= $("#P703_ROWS_NUM").val();
    if(num==0){
    $("#P703_AREAS_INVESTIGACION").css('background-color','red'); 
    }  
  });
```

The variable takes correctly the value 
But it doesn't work.
Please Help me.

Comment: Run $("#P703_AREAS_INVESTIGACION") in the browser console and check it returns something. CSS specificity may also override your colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery understands `background-color` and `backgroundColor`. Try using a value (RGB) **red**:

```
$("#P703_AREAS_INVESTIGACION").css('background-color', '#f00');
```

Or, you can use:

```
$("#P703_AREAS_INVESTIGACION").css({'background-color': 'red'});
```